# Generate regular expression for my tcpdump output

Tags: python, regex

I have following line from TCP dump output

```
09:42:57.346128 IP 192.16.0.1.60800 > 184.84.166.118.49331: Flags [.], seq 62929:65665, ack 0, win 2715, options [nop,nop,TS val 2855068190 ecr 1673141977], length 2736
```

I have following python code to derive Flag info from it.

```
sentence = "09:42:57.346128 IP 192.16.0.1.60800 > 184.84.166.118.49331: Flags [.], seq 62929:65665, ack 0, win 2715, options [nop,nop,TS val 2855068190 ecr 1673141977], length 2736"
pattern=re.compile(r'Flags\s\[.*\]')
matches=pattern.finditer(sentence )

for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

and output is

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(209, 305), match='Flags [.S], seq 62929:65665, ack 0, win 2715, opt>
```

You can see its taking things even after "Flags [.S]" which i do not want.
i think my regular expression "**r'Flags\s[.*]'**"means

- Flags: Start searching for string that starts with "Flags"
- \s: then a space
- [: Followed by a "[" bracket sign
- .: Next character can be anything
- *: next can be  zero or one character
- [: next shall be "]"

but why its overshooting and giving additional data?
if i make regular expression like "**r'Flags\s[.*?]'**" its returning correct result. Why so?

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets are special characters in the `re` language and must be escaped. They are escaped in the first example, but not in the follow-up.

Also, the next character cannot really be *anything*: it could be anything *but* a closing square bracket. So, the right regex is `r'Flags\s\[[^\]+]\]'`.

You can describe the same pattern using an alternative language. By default, the `'.*'` operator is *greedy*: it matches as many characters as it can, including the first closing square bracket, and stops only at the last square bracket. The addition of `?` (`'.*?'`) makes it non-greedy, and it will stop at the *first* occurrence of a square bracket. That is why `r'Flags\s[.*?]'` works (but must be `r'Flags\s[.+?]'`, unless you allow empty flags).

Answer (score 0):

@DyZ provided a good answer. However, at least with Python 2.7.14, I do not get the second match results you folks mentioned when using `r'Flags\s[.*?]'`

```
 m = re.search(r'Flags\s\[.*\]', sentence); m.group()
Out[117]: 'Flags [.], seq 62929:65665, ack 0, win 2715, options [nop,nop,TS val 2855068190 ecr 1673141977]'
```

So that's the first match and like you said, it is matching more than you want. The reason is that .* matches any characters.

However, note that I had to escape `[` and `]`, because `[]` has a special meaning. [`any_chars_inside`] will match **any "1"** of the characters inside [].

There is an exception, if you will. Special characters like ., *, ? (, ) lose their meaning. So [.*] means match '.' or '*' literal chars. That's why `[.]` means match the literal char '.', which does not come right after `\s`, so search should fail.

If you escape with `\[ \]`, then

```
\[.*\] means match everything that starts with [ and then whatever.
```

if you change that to `\[.*?\]`, then you are telling the regex to stop if it finds `]`. As @Dyz explained, "?" is making the search non-greedy, i.e. do not try to match everything.

With that in mind, @Dyz's suggestion `r'Flags\s\[[^\]+]\]'` will work, as would

```
r'Flags\s\[.*?\]'
```

which literally means, `match Flags`, then `a space`, then `[`, then any number of chars until you hit `]`

Re-pro your first match:

`> m = re.search(r'Flags\s\[.*\]', sentence); m.group()
Out[117]: 'Flags [.], seq 62929:65665, ack 0, win 2715, options [nop,nop,TS val 2855068190 ecr 1673141977]'`

Here is the result of what I suggested above:

`> m = re.search(r'Flags\s\[.*?\]', sentence); m.group()
Out[118]: 'Flags [.]'`

and here is the failure I get if you I put in what you said worked:

`m = re.search(r'Flags\s[.*?]', sentence); m.group()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\2.7.12\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-119-fd472f0d5ebb>", line 1, in <module>
    m = re.search(r'Flags\s[.*?]', sentence); m.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Answer (score 0):

> The repetition operators "*" and "+" in the regex context are greedy in nature. Greedy operators will match characters as much as they can.
>
> For example, I have a string "hello@world@from@my@house" and a regex r".*@". It will match "hello@world@from@my@".
>
> But if you add the character "?" after "*", the first match will be "hello@". The "?" character makes the "*" operator lazy, it will try to match the regex as less characters as possible.

Feel free to check this tutorial for regular expression repetition [Repetition](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).